# Tilemap Coordinates for Tiled hexagons

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been wrestling with this and decided to ask for assistance.

Scenario:

Tiles Width: 340  Height: 160

By definition, a hexagon has 6 equal sides.  With the above dimensions that's no longer the case.  It more resembles a diamond.  Finding the coordinates for a traditional hexagon in cocos2d is easily located in a Google search.  I can't figure out the equation I need to calculate tile coordinates in the irregular hexagon.  When sketched on paper it's essentially two isosceles trapezoids.  On the cocos2d forums I found someone else with the same problem [cocos2d post]: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/17253.

Can anyone offer a solution or guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it enough to scale it? Use functions you found for equally sided hexagon, create grid with hexagon side 160 and scale grid on width by 340/160.

Comment: I was making the problem way more complicated than it needed to be.  I solved it by using CGRectContainsPoint.  The tilemap is already loaded with all the tiles details.  I merely had to convert the touched location (scaled if necessary) and brute force thru each tile till I found the tile the point was contained in.